# UK Postcode Database With Co-ordinates

Tags: database, postal-code

I've downloaded a database from here which seems to be just what I need:
- http://www.freemaptools.com/download-uk-postcode-lat-lng.htm

Except for the fact it doesn't appear to contain Northern Ireland postcodes. Does anyone know what I can do about this or have any alternatives? Even if it means purchasing a database

Answer (score 2):

We used to use [PAF](http://www.royalmail.com/marketing-services-regular/choose-your-audience/data-management) for postcode mapping its a paid one.

EDIT: Updated the one from Royal Mail, all the providers pick data from Royal Mail anyways.

Comment: this is the definitive list.

Comment: Thanks, is that site legit though? Can't help but think it looks a little untrustworthy going by its design

Comment: Updated the link pealo, if you look at the address management section you will find the information for pricing and programming

Answer (score 1):

how many do you look up ?

I use google maps API quite often for lookups

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=POSTCODE&sensor=false
```

Comment: Thanks, this could be an option! I've just been reading up more on it here http://ben-major.co.uk/2012/02/using-google-maps-to-lookup-uk-postcodes/ 

Shame about the request limit, but it does provide a handy way to get around it with your own db

Answer (score 1):

There's also the Ordnance Survey Code-Point Open database.

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html

> Code-Point® Open contains a list of all the current postcode units in Great Britain, each of   which has a precise geographic location at a resolution of 1 metre.

Do check that the OS OpenData license is suitable for your purpose though. It seems quite permissive, but you have to provide attribution.

Answer (score 0):

The licensing of the Northern Irish postcode data is more restrictive than the rest of the UK.   It isn't provided in OS Code Point but is provided in the ONS postcode data, which I think is better anyway, since it includes historic data. There's no direct link to their data but you can search for it from here, http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/guide-method/geography/products/postcode-directories/-nspp-/index.html. Check the licensing of the NI data, since you won't be able to use it on a commercial site, unless you pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to answer but I have bumped into a similar need and found a paid UK postal code database at http://www.worldcitiesdatabase.com/postal-code-database.aspx
But I checked with the support team and they do not sell for individual countries and it appears costly to me. Did you find any better option?

Answer (score 0):

No reason to spend alot of money for this..here is a link for a simple API with a low money cost usuage.. that allows obtaining GeoJson for googlemaps..query by single or combining UK Postal Code(ex. ZE1 0AE) ,Sector, District, City, and Wards Boundaries

https://www.mashape.com/vanitysoft/uk-boundaries-io

[image: query by uk postal]